# JIRA OAuth process in Python

Tags: python, ssl, ssl-certificate, jira, jira-rest-api

I'm using the below snippet to sign the request and get request tokens for JIRA OAuth process.

```
import base64
import urlparse
from tlslite.utils import keyfactory
import oauth2 as oauth

consumer_key = 'oauth-sample-consumer'
consumer_secret = 'dont_care'

request_token_url = 'https://localhost:8090/jira/plugins/servlet/oauth/request-token'
access_token_url = 'https://localhost:8090/jira/plugins/servlet/oauth/access-token'
authorize_url = 'https://localhost:8090/jira/plugins/servlet/oauth/authorize'

class SignatureMethod_RSA_SHA1(oauth.SignatureMethod):
    name = 'RSA-SHA1'

    def signing_base(self, request, consumer, token):
        if not hasattr(request, 'normalized_url') or request.normalized_url is None:
            raise ValueError("Base URL for request is not set.")

        sig = (
            oauth.escape(request.method),
            oauth.escape(request.normalized_url),
            oauth.escape(request.get_normalized_parameters()),
        )

        key = '%s&' % oauth.escape(consumer.secret)
        if token:
            key += oauth.escape(token.secret)
        raw = '&'.join(sig)
        return key, raw

    def sign(self, request, consumer, token):
        """Builds the base signature string."""
        key, raw = self.signing_base(request, consumer, token)

        with open('../rsa.pem', 'r') as f:
            data = f.read()
        privateKeyString = data.strip()

        privatekey = keyfactory.parsePrivateKey(privateKeyString)
        signature = privatekey.hashAndSign(raw)

        return base64.b64encode(signature)


if __name__=='__main__':
    consumer = oauth.Consumer(consumer_key, consumer_secret)
    client = oauth.Client(consumer)
    client.set_signature_method(SignatureMethod_RSA_SHA1())

    resp, content = client.request(request_token_url, "POST")
    if resp['status'] != '200':
       raise Exception("Invalid response %s: %s" % (resp['status'],  content))
```

I have added the public key to JIRA consumer application. Now executing the above snippet always gives me this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "views.py", line 80, in <module>
    resp, content = client.request(request_token_url, "GET")
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/oauth2/__init__.py", line 682, in request
    connection_type=connection_type)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/httplib2/__init__.py", line 1570, in request
    (response, content) = self._request(conn, authority, uri, request_uri, method, body, headers, redirections, cachekey)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/httplib2/__init__.py", line 1317, in _request
    (response, content) = self._conn_request(conn, request_uri, method, body, headers)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/httplib2/__init__.py", line 1252, in _conn_request
    conn.connect()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/httplib2/__init__.py", line 1044, in connect
    raise SSLHandshakeError(e)
httplib2.SSLHandshakeError: [Errno 1] _ssl.c:503: error:14090086:SSL routines:SSL3_GET_SERVER_CERTIFICATE:certificate verify failed
```

I actually deleted my public key and again entered it in my consumer app to make sure there are no white spaces.

JIRA doesn't give any option to upload a public key file, so it has to be copied anyhow.

Answer (score 1):

I got it solved using this `certifi` package

```
sudo pip install certifi
```

In code:

```
client.ca_certs = certifi.where()
```